# Rails - CanCan - If can? works on page load but not via a AJAX Partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

Hello I have the following in a partial.

```
<% if can? :update, @permission %>
Yes
<% end %>
```

For the exact same user, when this loads via html this works great. But when I render that partial via ajax, as so:

```
$('#current').html('<%=escape_javascript(render :partial =>"permissions/teammembers", :locals => {:teammembers => @teammembers}) %>');
```

Then cancan is return false, why is that? the current_user is the same person making the request?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check if @permission is not nil. Throw it and see if it is ok.